# React on Rails and action cable and openai data parser issue

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stream, openai-api

My requirement is get the stream data from OpenAI and display to UI. I've used react as front-end and rails as back-end. The action cable is being used for streaming purpose. I'm getting stream data from OpenAi(ruby-openai gem) properly but it is difficult to parse in react end. Is there any lib for it?. I need to parse stream data to JSON objects. Stream data comes words by words. Output comes in string format

**Sample response from cable:**

```
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to channelname:: {:voc_data=>""}                                                                                                                                                          
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to channelname:: {:voc_data=>"{\""}                                                                                                                                                       
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to channelname:: {:voc_data=>"product"}                                                                                                                                                   
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to channelname:: {:voc_data=>"_a"}                                                                                                                                                        
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to channelname:: {:voc_data=>"\":{\""}                                                                                                                                                    
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to channelname:: {:voc_data=>"posit"}                                                                                                                                                     
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to channelname:: {:voc_data=>"ives"}                                                                                                                                                      
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to channelname:: {:voc_data=>"\":\""}                                                                                                                                                     
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to channelname:: {:voc_data=>"The"}                                                                                                                                                       
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to channelname:: {:voc_data=>" Kh"}                                                                                                                                                       
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to channelname:: {:voc_data=>"adi"}                                                                                                                                                       
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to channelname:: {:voc_data=>" Natural"}                                                                                                                                                  
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to channelname:: {:voc_data=>" A"}                                                                                                                                                        
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to channelname:: {:voc_data=>"ml"}
```

**Openai stream part in rails:**

```
data_append = ""
client.chat(
  parameters: {
    model: get_model,
    messages: [{ role: "user", content: get_prompt}],
    max_tokens: 1000,
    temperature: 0.7,
    stream: proc do |chunk, _bytesize|
      if chunk.dig("choices", 0, "finish_reason") != "stop"
        content = chunk.dig("choices", 0, "delta", "content")
        print content
        data_append += content
        push_to_target_channel(data_append)
      end
    end
  }
)
```

**Receiving data in react:**

```
useEffect(() => {    
    let arr = [];
    consumer.subscriptions.create(
    {
      channel: 'channelname',
    },
    {
      connected: () => {
        console.log('connected')
      },
      disconnected: () => {
        console.log('disconnected')
      },
      received: (new_data) => {
        setData(new_data)
      }
    }
  ) 
}, [data])
```

Comment: My first instinct would be to buffer the response on the backend and send to the frontend when it's ready. there is no point in sending partial JSON to frontend, because it's invalid and can't be used. And then you would need to `eval` it anyway, which opens you up to many possible security issues